# Christmas Tree trunk in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to draw a christmas tree in C# and have managed to draw the actual tree, but im having issues with drawing the trunk in the middle of the tree. The issue is that the trunk is actually printed at the start of the end of the tree and not just straight in the middle.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get's current console window size
        int origWidth = Console.WindowWidth;

        int spaces = origWidth/2;
        int widthOfTree = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the height of the desired razor tree");
        int treeHeightUserInput = 0;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out treeHeightUserInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid number!");               
        }

        // draws tree
        for (int i = 0; i < treeHeightUserInput; i++)
        {
            // indentation
            for (int j = 0; j < spaces; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < widthOfTree; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("* ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            widthOfTree++;
            // reduces width of next line
            spaces--;
        }

        // draws trunk
        for (int i = 0; i < treeHeightUserInput / 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < spaces; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < widthOfTree / 3; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("| ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

That's how it looks, I'm not really sure where the issue is as I'm pretty much reusing the same code that I used to draw the tree but just reduced the height and thickness by 2/3. Does anyone have a guess?
[image: End Result Tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `spaces` goes towards 0 in the `draws tree` loop, which is what makes your tree leaves triangular, but then when you draw the trunk you carry on using `spaces` as whatever it became when you finished drawing the leaves, meaning your trunk is aligned with the left edge of the leaves (the bottom left of the triangle)

If you want to offset your trunk away from the same indent level as the bottom left corner of the leaves, you'll have to have to increase `spaces` before you reach this loop:

```
        // indentation
        for (int j = 0; j < spaces; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to calc a suitable value for `spaces` before running the `indentation` loop

Comment: It's not exactly 0 but `origWidth/2 - userInput`

Comment: @Orace may i ask why the userInput is of any importance here? As I'm just using the userInput to declare the height of the tree. Or do you mean because the tree can technically end before space reaches 0 if the height of the tree isn't high enough?

Comment: I adjusted the wording of true post; I'd assumed 0 because I thought the left edge of the tree touched the left edge of the console regardless the height. Orace observed that `spaces` ended up as width/2-userinput because `spaces` Starts at origwidth/2, and then is decremented by one for every line of tree height loop

Comment: @Mike_AZ because userInput also gives the tree width and the trunk horizontal start and end positions depend on the tree width.

Answer (score 0):

`spaces` is decremented when the top part of the tree is drawn (`spaces--`). So it's value doesn't match your needs, you have to reset it or increments it (by `treeHeightUserInput/3`) before the loop that draw the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Caius Jard, I was able to somewhat solve the issue. I doubt that it's a clean way to solve it, but it works.

```
            // draws trunk
        int trunk = origWidth / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < treeHeightUserInput / 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < trunk - ((widthOfTree + 1) / 3); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < widthOfTree / 3; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("| ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: For readability, you can rename trunk to `trunkStart` initialize it to `origWidth/2 - ((widthOfTree + 1) / 3)`  and write the first inner for loop like this: `for (int j = 0; j < trunkStart; j++)`